# Very basic SQL script with aggregate

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
select Customers.cust_id, count(Orders.cust_id)  
from Customers left outer join Orders  
on Customers.cust_id=Orders.cust_id  
group by Customers.cust_id
```

This correctly displays everything.

```
select Customers.cust_id, ***Customers.cust_name***, count(Orders.cust_id)  
from Customers left outer join Orders  
on Customers.cust_id=Orders.cust_id  
group by Customers.cust_id
```

,,Your query does not include the specified expression 'cust_name' as port of an aggregate function."

Why is that? Each cust_id in Customers has a name in cust_name. Why do I get this error message?

Comment: *Each cust_id in Customers has a name in cust_name.*...Access does not know that. Should it take your word for it? Simply add `cust_name` to `group by` clause as all non-aggregated columns must be specified as a grouping in aggregate SQL queries.

Comment: The error message is telling you **precisely and clearly** what the problem is - **your query does not include *cust_name* as part of an aggregate function**. That means it needs to be listed in the `GROUP BY` clause. You should learn to actually **read the words** in error messages; they almost always convey actual meaning. The rule is: If it's not part of an aggregate (IOW, not included in a function by (), as in `COUNT()`, `AVG()`, or `MAX()`), it needs to be listed in the GROUP BY.

Comment: ... unless you're using MySql, which violates and ansi standard here .

Comment: This comes up regularly in the Stack Overflow [ms-access] tags: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-access%5D+not+include+aggregate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an aggregate function `count()` all other fields (that aren't used with an aggregate function) must appear in the `Group By` clause.

---

Here is my explanation as to why:

Aggregate functions operate across groups.

(That is, unless no groups or other fields are specified, in which case they operate across the whole recordset by default. For example, `SELECT Sum(Salary) FROM Staff` works.)

If you group by `cust_id` then it knows what to output, a count for each `cust_id`. But what would it do with the `cust_name`'s? Which `cust_name` would it, or should it, display for each `cust_id` output? What if there are several `cust_name`'s for a `cust_id`? It will only display one row for each `cust_id`, so what name should it display alongside it? It won't make the assumption that there is exactly one `cust_name` to correspond to one `cust_id`.

If there is one `cust_name` per `cust_id` then grouping by both will produce the same number of rows (as for `cust_id` alone) and provide consistent, and reliable, behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask why? I really want to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Customers.cust_id, Customers.cust_name, count(Orders.cust_id)  
from Customers left outer join Orders  
on Customers.cust_id=Orders.cust_id  
group by Customers.cust_id, Customers.cust_name
```